# How to Setup Jenkins for IOS simulator using Appium Server from Mac

Tags: ios, jenkins, appium, simulator

I've designed a framework using BDD in Java and using Appium Maven, for iOS Simulator and real Device which works totally fine in local machine.

but When I configure to Jenkins, Its working fine for Real device but for Simulator, Jenkins to not talking appium server.

Is there any plugins or configs changes i need to follow.

PS: As of now, I'm running Jenkins in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

We should allow Jenkins to Run GUI Applications:

Follow this link for configuration steps on Mac:

[Jenkins Mac Setup to Open iOS Simulator](http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/)